# Android proguarded apk still readable

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, apk, android-proguard, apktool

I tried to proguard my app. It successfully obfuscated the apk. However, when i try to view the java code of my apk using Apk_oneclick, I am able to. I have created a release version of my apk. Still the problem persist. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

build.gradle:

[image]

Proguard Rules:

[image]

Java code from the release-apk:

[image]

Comment: If screenshot of proguard rules file is not changed - you haven't any rule - they all are comented

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I fixed the issue. Added some proguard rules and cleaned the project. Its working fine now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. Cleaned the project and ran the same with some changes in the Proguard rules.

Answer (score 1):

For enabling ProGuard configurations for your application you need to enable it in your module level gradle file. you need to set the value of `minifyEnabled true`.

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

You can also enable `shrinkResources true` which will remove resources that ProGuard flaggs as unused.

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set following property 
and add some rules in proguard-android

```
  buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```